# @Condition problem getting properties values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot application and I need to implement a conditional bean based on the DB provider. The problem is that when I'm trying to get the property with @Value tag i'm getting null value.

I have tried creating another class or tagging the `extends Condition` class with @Component/@Services, but it doesn work either

```
@Component
public class PostgreSQLProviderCondition implements Condition{

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dbConnectionString;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return dbConnectionString.contains("postgresql"); //Null pointer exception :c
    }
}
```

I have also tried creating a new class with all the properties, but when I do the `@Autowired` I get null too.

Here is the config class implementation:

```
@Configuration
public class SQLProviderConfiguration{
    @Bean
    @Conditional(PostgreSQLProviderCondition.class)
    public IFilingNumberSQLProvider filingProviderPostgreSQL() {
        return new FilingNumberSQLProviderPostgreSQL();
    }


    @Bean
    @Conditional(SQLServerProviderCondition.class)
    public IFilingNumberSQLProvider filingProviderSQLServer() {
        return new FilingNumberSQLProviderSQLServer();
    }
}
```

And the boostrap.yml config file looks like this:

```
spring:
  profiles: offline
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
  jmx:
    default-domain: ****
  datasource:
    url: ****
    username: ****
    password: ****
    hikari:
      pool-name: *****
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
        default_schema: msa_data
        current_session_context_class: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
    generate-ddl: true
```

Comment: could you use @PropertySource("here you put the path to you yml file")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question but I believe solves the underlying requirement.

You can use `@ConditionalOnExpression` to only only apply the configuration when a SpEL is valid. For your case you could have:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${spring.datasource.url}'.contains('postgresql')")
```